# How to split tuple in python

Tags: python, split, tuples

How do I split tuple from dictionary

```
dic = {('K30', 'K56'): 1}
```

to get this output in a text file:

```
K30    K56    1
```

what I tried is

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    a,b = k.split(',') 
    print >>f, a+'\t',b+'\t',v
f.close()
```

but I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not split you can simply say

```
 a,b = k
```

Comment: or `for (a, b), v in dic.items():`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
for k,v in dic.items(): 
print >>f, k[0]+'\t',k[1]+'\t',v f.close()
```

Just access the tuple elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    print '\t'.join(k),'\t',v
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all the good ones are taken, here goes a concise version

```
[print(k[0],k[1],v) for k,v in dic.items()]
```